# How much is decidability compromised within this restriction of the fixpoint combinator?

Tags: halting-problem, haskell, decidability, fixed-point

Though purely functional programming languages, such as Haskell, is commonly thought to have no side-effects, there is a caveat: **Recursive calls may hang.**

I considered this to be undesirable, and thought about what if I force every recursive call to halt.

Formally, for every recursive call, the fixpoint combinator `fix :: (a -> a) -> a` shall be fed with a function whose return value has a directly identifiable constructor. For examples, the following functions are viable to be fed to `fix`:

- `\_ -> 0` (whose fixpoint is `0`)
- `\xs -> 0 : xs` (whose fixpoint is `[0,0,0,...]`)
- `\xs -> 0 : fmap (+1) xs` (whose fixpoint is `[0,1,2,...]`)
- `\mx -> Just (case mx of {Nothing -> 0; _ -> 1})` (whose fixpoint is `Just 1`)

But the followings are not:

- `\x -> x :: Int`
- `\x -> 1 + x`
- `\xs -> fmap (+1) xs`
- `\mx -> case mx of {Nothing -> Just 0; _ -> Just 1}` (`Just 1` is a fixpoint, but the `Just` part isn't directly identifiable. Indeed, GHC fails to recognize it.)

How much would decidability be compromised by this restriction? That is, what decidable problems would have its decidability unrecognizable? There will be a strict compromise because the halting problem is unsolvable. A counterexample would be sufficient.

Sidenote: If an actual infinite loop is needed, one can encapsulate it in the `IO` monad. In other words, `mfix :: (a -> IO a) -> IO a` can be fed with everything.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_functional_programming

Comment: Also: https://www.ioc.ee/~tarmo/tday-veskisilla/uustalu-slides.pdf

Comment: Worth noting that it's very easy to have non-termination in Haskell via various sources other than `fix`.